# The if condition always return true

Tags: javascript, jquery

please help here: the if condition always return true though it is false??
these are the html code for variable div and variable your at the beginning

```
(<div class="div" id="div" style="background:yellow"></div>) 
(<input type="text" id="your">)

$(document).ready(function generate() {
        "use strict";
        var x = $(".2").text(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10))),
            z = $(".3").text(Math.floor((Math.random() * 10)));

        $(".div").text(x.text() + z.text());
    });



        var show = document.getElementById("show"),
            your = document.getElementById("your").value,
            div = document.getElementById("div").textContent;
        show.onclick = function () {
            "use strict";
            if (your == div) {
                alert("yes");
            } else {
                alert("noo");
            }
        };
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging what so ever? What is `your` and `div` outputting?

Comment: And why have you flagged this as jQuery, when it's pure javascript? try adding a couple of console.log(your) and console.log(div) before the if statement, see what you get. For example, if both were undefined, then the equality is true.

Comment: so sorry for these mistakes ,yes in console the two values are empty, i will edit my question now..

Comment: can you add the HTML too please?

Comment: @dr-amira well empty values are quite same, aren't they?

Comment: yes yes ,I eddited the question and still do not know the reason for being empty..

Comment: Do you have actual HTML? What is creating the divs with the ids `show`, `your` and `div`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you are defining the values outside of the function. So in the onclick handler you are comparing the initial values.

If you want the actual values, you should access the values inside the function:

```
var show = document.getElementById("show"),
    your = document.getElementById("your"),
    div = document.getElementById("div");

show.onclick = function () {
    if (your.value == div.textContent) {
        alert("yes");
    } else {
        alert("noo");
    }
};
```